# Transpose rows into columns in excel based on referencing the first column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file with the below information

```
#Name           Image           Image   Image
product 1       image111A.jpg   image111B.jpg   
product 2       image222A.jpg   image222B.jpg   image222C.jpg
product 3       image333A.jpg   image333B.jpg
```

and would like to convert into like below in excel using macro or formula

```
#Name         Image
product 1     image111A.jpg
product 1     image111B.jpg
product 2     image222A.jpg
product 2     image222B.jpg
product 2     image222C.jpg
product 3     image333A.jpg
product 3     image333B.jpg
```

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://www.mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Answer (score 0):

Probably it should be something like the following. It can be done nicer, but then it would be harder to understand, I think.

```
Sub MakeItFlat()
Dim sourceSheet, targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim counterRow, counterColumn, counterTarget As Integer
Dim tempString As String
Set sourceSheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set targetSheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

counterRow = 0
counterTarget = 0
Do While sourceSheet.Range("A1").Offset(counterRow, 0).Value <> ""
    tempString = sourceSheet.Range("A1").Offset(counterRow, 0).Value
    counterColumn = 1
    Do While sourceSheet.Range("A1").Offset(counterRow, counterColumn).Value <> ""
        targetSheet.Range("A1").Offset(counterTarget, 0).Value = tempString
        targetSheet.Range("A1").Offset(counterTarget, 1).Value = _ 
             sourceSheet.Range("A1").Offset(counterRow, counterColumn).Value
        counterTarget = counterTarget + 1
        counterColumn = counterColumn + 1
    Loop
    counterRow = counterRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```